# pgAdmin4: "can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str"

Tags: pgadmin-4

Using `pgAdmin4`, but whenever I choose to view the create script of available views I get the above error. Also, if I choose to see view's `SELECT` script, to only shows `[object Object]`

```
# View -> Scripts -> CREATE Script
can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

# View -> Scripts -> SELECT Script
[object Object]
```

Any fix to this?

```
# version info 
pgAmin4: version 6.15

# os
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears this issue was [reported](https://postgrespro.com/list/id/1460054040.2949491.1568778689742@mail.yahoo.com) in `pgadmin4 v4.12`. Unfortunately, it resurfaced in `v6.15`. The workaround that work for me is to downgrade to `v6.9`

```
sudo apt -y remove pgadmin4
sudo apt -y autoremove  pgadmin4*
sudo apt -y install pgadmin4*=6.9 pgadmin4-server*=6.9

# Configure the webserver, if you installed pgadmin4-web:
sudo /usr/pgadmin4/bin/setup-web.sh
```